# Estimating the $L^p$ norm of a second derivative of a solution of the Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

Consider Dirichlet boundary value problem on unit disk : $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$.

Then, is there a constant $c>0$ satisfying the following?

-For every solution $u$ that $\int_0^{2\pi}\left|\frac{d^2u(e^{it})}{dt^2}\right|^p dt\le 1$, $\|u_{xx}\|_p\le c$

(as long as the all integrals are well-defined)

P.S. You may assume $u$ to be either strong or classical(or else), as you please.

Comment: Looks reasonable. Looking at the tangential derivative, we see it convolved with the Poisson kernel, so that's bounded. The derivative in normal direction is more problematic, but since the integral is over the disk, it should not be too bad.